# Jquery - Add Column left or right to previous Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have two buttons called "Add Column Left" and "Add Column Right". I need to get the Index of the clicked cell, so that I can get the column index and add the new column to the previous one.

My current code:

```
function AddColumn(addLeft){ // Which button is clicked? Add Left || Add Right

  var header = $('#tableHeader'); // Get the table header element
  var headerContentToAppend = "<th>Header</th>"; // The default text of the new header
  var table = $('#tableBody'); // Get the table body element
  var rowContentToAppend = "<td>Content</td>"; // The default text of the new cells

  // issue 1: missing index of the clicked/focussed column

  if (addLeft) { // Button "Add Column Left" clicked
    header.prepend(headerContentToAppend); // Add the Column to the left of the previous column
  }
  else { // Button "Add Column Right" clicked
    header.append(headerContentToAppend); // Add the Column to the right of the previous column
  }

  $('table th').last().attr("contenteditable", true).focus(); // set all cells editable and focus the last one
  table.find("tr").each(function() { // Get all existing rows ....

        // issue 2: maybe the cells don't match to the right column, I have to test this after finishing the first issue

          $(this).append(rowContentToAppend); // ... and add cells to the new column
      });
}
```

So my problem is  to get the right index of the clicked column. After adding a new column i have to fill it up with new cells below.

I placed two comments called "issue" in the code, that should make things clear.

My HTML Code:

```
  <table id="dataTable">
    <thead id="tableHeader">
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I want to control the table by Javascript to keep it dynamic.

Comment: Did you notice there's a `index` function in jQuery ?

Comment: No, but thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you could use the method **[`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** to get the element index :

```
var index = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').index($(this));
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var index = 0;

function AddColumn(addLeft){
  var header = $('#tableHeader');
  var headerContentToAppend = "<th>Header</th>";
  var table = $('#tableBody');
  var rowContentToAppend = "<td>Content</td>";

  if (addLeft)
    header.find('th').eq(index).before(headerContentToAppend); 
  else
    header.find('th').eq(index).after(headerContentToAppend);

  $('table th').attr("contenteditable", true).last().focus();

  table.find("tr").each(function() {
    if (addLeft)
      $(this).find('td').eq(index).before(rowContentToAppend); 
    else 
      $(this).find('td').eq(index).after(rowContentToAppend); 
  });
  
  $('td').removeClass('selected');
}

$('body').on('click','td',function(){
  $('td').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');

  index = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').index($(this));
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead id='tableHeader'>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tableBody'>
    <tr>
      <td>column 1</td>
      <td>column 2</td>
      <td>column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>column 11</td>
      <td>column 22</td>
      <td>column 33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>column 111</td>
      <td>column 222</td>
      <td>column 333</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button onClick='AddColumn(true)'>&lt; Add to the Left</button>
<button onClick='AddColumn(false)'>Add to the Right &gt;</button>
```

Comment: It always returns -1, do I have to use a click event?

Comment: And please what you mean by _I need to get the Index of the clicked cell_ is the cell that will be clicked or one of the buttons or the both? not really clear.

Comment: Just added the HTML code. When the cell is clicked and focussed, it should return the index of the column, the cell is placed in.

Comment: I think `$('td').click(function(){
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
});` may help me

Comment: True you may have to use the click on td, but no need for the other function they will do the same as my suggested `  index = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').index($(this));`. check my update.